# Passing a property of a registred type into a constructor of another using xml configuration

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, xml-configuration

I wan to configure the unity container using ONLY xml (no fluent API) and I have a complex task.
I have an interface which looks like this

```
public interface ISettingsDistributor {
    String TargetProperty;
}
```

And its implementation `SettingsDistributor`

```
public interface ISettingsConsumer { }
public class SettingsConsumer :ISettingsConsumer, OtherType {
    public SettingsConsumer(String theParameter) : base(theParameter) {

    }
}
```

This is a consumer of that setting. The following is the configuration section I've built so far. (`typeAlias`es and other stuff is omitted)

```
   <containers>
        <container name="container">
            <types>
                <type type="ISettingsDistributor" mapTo="SettingsDistributor">
                    <lifetime type="singleton" />
                </type>
                <type type="ISettingsConsumer" mapTo="SettingsConsumer">
                    <lifetime type="perThread" />
                </type>                    
            </types>
        </container>
    </containers>
```

How can I say to unity in this xml file that when it tries to resolve the type `ISettingsConsumer` it should first resolve the `ISettingsDistributor` and inject its `TargetProperty` member as a value to the constructor?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do such an ugly thing? In almost all applications it is enough to have just a few extension possibilities. You don't want to replace everything. Just these extension points should be configured using xml. For everything else the fluent API is the better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just inject your ISettingsDistributor?It will be the source of your magic string anyway.So whats the problem with  that?